# receiving variables from php exec function

Tags: php, exec, send

I'd like to send 3 variables from one php file to another using the exec function. 
How do I use the variables in the file that they are sent to?
Do they behave as previously declared variables or do I need to use something like $_GET to read them in?

Comment: Don't use exec(). Use include().

Alternatively you could write the other PHP file to take arguments on the command line, do the exec() as `exec("php otherfile.php var1 var2 var3")` and in `otherfile.php` you would get the vars via `$argv[1], $argv[2], $argv[3]` (yes, those numbers are correct). See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php   But I still recommend you use include() instead.

Comment: this syntax: exec("php file.php $var1 $var2 var3l");

Comment: it returns a HTTP ERROR 500. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You might have to give the full path to the otherfile.php. IDK where your files live and where the web server runs from. Another reason I recommend include().

Comment: they are both in the same directory.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation

Comment: The files may be in the same directory but exec() has nothing to do with that, exec() will be operating out of the working directory of the webserver executing the PHP. So again, try the complete path, as I suggested.

FWIW include() *does* work from the context of the file it's used in so in *that* case relative path works. exec() is telling the PHP interpreter to open a fork and run a command line. You probably need to read up on how software programs function on a computer if you don't see what I'm saying.

Comment: We needed another fork to the command line, that was the intention. Using the full directory works, thank you.

Comment: BTW I wasn't trying to be snotty, it was a literal "if you don't get what i'm saying, read up on X."

Answer (score 0):

$argv ist the answer. You can read here
http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: For this to be helpful I think you need to include code that shows how to send and receive the variables.